# Pop random element from a set - JS

Tags: javascript

In e.g. Python if we have a set we can call set.pop() and it will remove a value from the set and return it.

I'm working through an algorithms question in JS where I need to do this. But there doesn't seem to be a way to, as the set.delete() function expects a value, and I don't have access to the values. Is there an easy work around?

Comment: @vsync agreed on being XY, not sure what you propose is the X. Might just be "how I get any value from a Set" without having to be a random every time. The first (or last) might also be sufficient. OP should clarify what the real requirement is.

Comment: Please show us the code because I don't really understand the question 100%

Comment: Put all the possible values in an array and randomize a number, then access the array at that index. And there you have it - the value which should now be randomly removed. use that value when calling `delete()`

Comment: @vsync "just put all the possible values in an array and randomize a number and there you have it - the value which should now be randomly removed. use that value when calling delete()" - yeah, I guess my question was whether there was a simpler way to do this in JS. But I guess not. TY though

Answer (score 3):

If saying "random" you mean any element, then this is a solution:

```js
function shiftSet(set) {
  for (const value of set) {
    set.delete(value)
    return value
  }
}

const set = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
shiftSet(set) // 'a'
set // {'b', 'c'}
```

It removes the earliest element added to the stack and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the values. (It would be faster than converting it to an array.)

```js
function deleteRandomElement(set) {
  if (set.size > 0) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*set.size);
      let i = 0;
      
      for(const value of set) {
        if(i === randomIndex) {
          set.delete(value);
          break;
        }
        i++;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Depending how many times he wants to delete. You only convert to Array **once**. Your solution runs an iteration (N times) every time you want to delete something.

Comment: @vsync You would also have to update the array each time. If you update with splice, it's O(N). If you update the array with delete, it's O(1) but you may run into the problem of choosing a random index from the array that has already been deleted, which would require you to regenerate the random index. A linked list might be a good compromise, but you'd need to make sure you're updating that linked list anytime you add to the set too.